# How can I remove an application which is preventing me from logging in normally on my MacBook?

Tags: applications, macos

MacBook Air 2015.

Today I installed a third party application. After that my MacBook is stuck loading after entering my password. I remember selecting “allow application on start of MacBook” so that whenever I restart my Mac that application will automatically start.

That application is stopping my Macbook from starting because it is a third party application and created by an unofficial developer (publisher) so whenever that application will start we need to click “run” manually because I am using latest version of macOS and in that there’s no option to allow application from unofficial/unlisted developer.

I am able to login using safe mode, but this application is not showing in safe mode.

How can I remove (uninstall) this application from my MacBook without losing my data?

Comment: When booted into Safe mode, have you tried just deleting this third party application from the Applications folder? What is the _name_ of this app?

Comment: That's going to depend a lot on what that app is, how it installs, what components it installs, etc.

Comment: I'd download and run etrecheck.  It should identify where this app is running from. https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250000632

Comment: @historystamp this would work without logging into the faulty account?